# How to identify the person in the middle?

Tags: preposiciones, adjetivos

En este grupo de personas, ¿cómo se puede identificar la chica más alta según su posición en el grupo?

¿Cuáles de estos ejemplos son correctos (o incorrectos) o cuál es la la forma mas correcta de decir "The person in the middle is the tallest"?

- La persona en el centro es la más alta.
- La persona del centro es la más alta.
- La persona del medio es la más alta.
- La personal de el medio es la más alta.
- La persona en el medio es la más alta.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/df/French_Indochina_100_Piastres.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La más correcta es *la persona del medio*. ¿Por qué?

1. ¿Por qué *del* y no *en el*? Porque es la forma habitual en español: *la persona del medio*, *el hombre de la derecha*, *la niña de más atrás*, *el estante de arriba*, *el florero de encima de la mesa*, etc. Muchas veces un hablante de inglés se sentirá tentado a copiar la misma estructura que se usa en inglés en estos casos, usando una preposición de lugar (*in*, *at*, *on*, etc.), pero en español se usa siempre *de* para determinar algo con su posición.
2. ¿Por qué *el medio* y no *el centro*? Porque en un grupo (de personas u objetos), si hay una cantidad fácil de contar y las cosas o personas están en una fila o en un orden claro, lo más habitual es decir *el/la X del medio* para señalar el que ocupa la posición del medio. Se diría *el centro* si se tratase de un grupo muy grande o sin un orden claro, porque *el centro* indica un lugar en el espacio, no una posición en una serie ordenada.

Comment: ¿Se puede decir *la de en medio*?

Comment: Lo he escuchado, sí.

Answer (score 3):

La opción 3 está mal, "de el" debería ser "del" pero obviando ese detalle utilizaría algo referido al medio (opciones 3, 4 y 5) en particular, optaría por la opción 3.

Supongo que "del medio" para mi hace referencia al "al medio del grupo" si dijera "del centro" o "en el centro" lo primero que pensaría yo es en la mujer ubicada en el centro de la imagen (la de blanco) y entiendo que no es lo que tu quieres transmitir.